# The phone do appears in Hcitool scan but not in Hcitool lescan.

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm trying to establish a connection between my android phone and a BLE Beacon device. The issue is I can see my beacon on my phone using CySmart app but my Beacon cannot find my phone using Lescan. 
The phone do appears in Hcitool scan but not in Hcitool lescan.

Comment: What kind of BLE device are you working with?  Is it a transmit only BLE beacon like iBeacon or something else?  How are you expecting the beacon to find your phone?  (If it is an iBeacon as this question is tagged, then iBeacons cannot see phones as they care transmit only.)

Comment: If you run `hcitool lescan` and you don't see a device you expect to see...  it's likely because it's not advertising.  But as David said, it's the iBeacon that should be advertising and the phone doing the scanning.

Comment: Yes it is a beacon device but I'm developing software for it so I have full control over it. Is there any way I can establish connection with my phone and send/receive data.